# Separate and Remove Results in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, delimiter, csv

I'm currently using a data extractor that allows you to run any JS of your choice to clean up your data.

Currently, the data in the columns I'm looking to clean up are being extracted as followed:

Column 1 (Shift Start):

- 7:0 - 7:15

Column 2 (Shift End):

- 11:15 - 11:30

I'm looking for a script that will strip and remove '- 7:15' from shift start and also remove '11:15 -' from Shift End.

I've initially started with using a script that splits the data into different columns by space and removing the unnecessary columns but I would prefer to just remove the parts of the data I don't need.

```
var cleanup = function(results) {

  // This example shows you can loop through each 
  // row of the data you scraped results and change the value each column

  //debugger;  // uncomment this line to enable debugging your script in Chrome Inspector  

  $.each(results, function(){                // loop through each row of scraped data

    var parts = this.values[0].split(' ');   // get value from column 1 and split it by ' '
    this.values[0] = parts[0];               // put part 1 back into first column
    this.values[1] = parts[1];               // put part 2 back into second column
  });

  return results;                            // return modified results
};
```